# Iptables selective MASQUERADE

Tags: networking, iptables, wireguard

I am working on a wireguard node for routing traffic. My plan is to allow wireguard peers to communicate with each other trough me (without masquerading) and create a separate forward from my private lan to wireguard, this time with masquerading. Is this possible? My current configuration is masquerading everything.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -o %i -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o %i -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o %i -j MASQUERADE
```

For those who don’t know, in wireguard %i will be replaced by your network device, in my case wg1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when all the network layout is under control, there's no need to add the rule when the tunnel is up and remove it later. It could be added once and for all beforehand, without any `iptables` rule in the WireGuard configuration. That's why I'm writing the normal commands below. Feel free to put back `%i` and complete with rule deletion commands if this is to be used in a WireGuard configuration file.

What is needed is a way to use the input interface in the POSTROUTING chain. Sadly, because the kernel used to not provide the incoming interface in the POSTROUTING hooks for routed packets, `iptables` doesn't allow this, so:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -i wg1 -o wg1 -j MASQUERADE
```

is rejected with `Can't use -i with POSTROUTING`.

Actually recent kernels ([version >= 5.5.x](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.5#Networking)) got this limitation lifted for the benefit of *nftables* and do provide the input interface in the POSTROUTING chain for routed packets, but there's still a check preventing the use of `-i interface` in *iptables*' POSTROUTING chain. It's possible (on such recent kernels) to circumvent the limitation by using `-i` in a user chain called from POSTROUTING:

```
iptables -t nat -N workaround
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg1 -j workaround
iptables -t nat -A workaround ! -i wg1 -j MASQUERADE
```

As it's not documented it's probably not a good idea.

So better use what has always been working: the IP source instead of the incoming interface. If the WireGuard routing system and its peers are all configured to use for examples IP addresses in the 192.0.2.0/24 block then this can be used:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -s 192.0.2.0/24 -o wg1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Of course *iptables* can be replaced with *nftables* and one can then simply use interface names:

```
nft add table ip handlewireguard
nft add chain ip handlewireguard natpostrouting '{ type nat hook postrouting priority 90; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip handlewireguard natpostrouting iifname != wg1 oifname wg1 masquerade
```